# Deleting feature classes in file geodatabase when context menu is disabled?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase

I have a file geodatabase with 20 feature classes and I need to delete a few of them, but the option to DELETE in ArcCatalog, if I select this feature class, and click right mouse, is disabled for the most of the feature classes in the file geodatabase.

Why is the reason for that? Can I fix it? This file geodatabase is created by xmlscheme of gdb.

Comment: Are they open in ArcMAP?

Comment: Nope. Just in arc catalog.

Comment: do you see any lock files in the .gdb file folder?

Comment: Do you have any map services consuming those fc?

Comment: Probably a lock (an opened reference to the dataset) or as @RyanDalton points out, it is compressed

Comment: Do you have ArcView License or Higher?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the solution was to remove feature classes from a topology in which they were participating before they could be deleted from the geodatabase.

Comment: A topology was not mentioned in your original question. Including such important details would have more quickly led to the answer :)

Comment: Ok. I did not know that:) But now I know :) We are here to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the file geodatabase is [compressed](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004v000000).

> Once compressed, a feature class or table is read-only and cannot be
>   edited. Compression is ideally suited to mature datasets that do not
>   require further editing. However, if required, a compressed dataset
>   can always be uncompressed to return it to its original, read-write
>   format.